# Google Analytics Log Level

Tags: logging, swift, google-analytics

How do I set the log level in swift for google analytics?

I have the line:

```
GAI.sharedInstance().logger.logLevel =
```

but I cannot find `kGAILogLevelVerbose` in the swift constants.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
GAI.sharedInstance().logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose;
```